# Timeout waiting to lock Artifact transforms cache (C:\Users\saad\.gradle\caches\transforms-3). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I am using vs code and trying to run flutter project on my android phone 
when I run it I get an error

> Timeout waiting to lock Artifact transforms cache (C:\Users\saad.gradle\caches\transforms-3). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.

How can I fix this ?